# Drive.Properties.get() - specify visibility

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Using the Advanced Drive Service in my google AppScript app:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive
I have a custom property PUBLIC called 'listingid' and am trying to get its value.
Unfortunately

```
Drive.Properties.get(fileId, 'listingid');
```

defaults to trying to get a PRIVATE property of that name, which is returning an error: `Property not found: key = listingid and visibility = PRIVATE`

I can't find any documentation for the method, and

```
Drive.Properties.get(fileId, 'listingid', 'PUBLIC');
```

doesn't work. Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: according to the docs here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/get, don't you have to use `gapi.client.drive.properties.get()` (see the Javascript section)?

Comment: That's for the basic Drive service. I'm trying to use the advanced one which lets me set custom properties. It's described here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive I suppose if all else fails I can use the basic one for the "get"

Comment: Sorry actually we're confusing App Script and straight up javascript here to begin with, so that wouldn't work in the first place.

Comment: ok. So is the basic drive interface not enough for get() through apps script?

Answer (score 0):

You can test on this at the following site:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/get
(go to the end of the site to test). Test and verify whether the property exists.

Comment: Property does exist, I tested it. Trying to use the Javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter supplied to `Drive.Properties.get()` must be an object with additional info, rather than a string. Though I could not find any documentation on what (if any) other properties are valid on the object, setting `visibility: 'PUBLIC'` seems to do the trick for me.

So for your example you should use something like

`var prop = Drive.Properties.get(fileId, 'listingid', {
    visibility: 'PUBLIC'
});
Logger.log('Property has value ' + prop.value);`

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
 Drive.Properties.get(fileId, 'listingid',{visibility:'PUBLIC'});